# How can I remove the translation key from en.json?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, i18next

I do not want to use the translation key in the json file.
I want the file to have only 2 levels, I mean I do not want to include the translation key on every locale file:

```
{
  "translation": {
    "sidebar": {
      "dashboard": "Dashboard",
      "clients": "Clients",
      "coaches": "Coaches",
      "candidates": "Candidates",
      "trackList": "Track List",
      "reports": "Reports"
    },
    "clients": {
      "clients": "Clients",
      "companyName": "Company Name",
      "previous": "Previous",
      "next": "Next"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my i18n.js file that initializes i18next.

```
import angular from 'angular';
import ngSanitize from 'angular-sanitize';
import i18next from 'i18next';
import ngI18next from 'ng-i18next';
import enLocale from './locales/en.json'

const module = angular.module('app.i18n', [ngSanitize, ngI18next]);

module
  .config(function() {

    window.i18next = i18next;

    i18next.init({
      debug: true,
      lng: 'en',
      fallbackLng: false,
      resources: {
        en: enLocale
      },
      useCookie: false,
      useLocalStorage: false
    }, function(err, t) {
      console.log('i18next was initialized');
      console.log( t('global.clients') );
      console.log( t('global.addNewClient') );
    });

});
export default module.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove translation from your Json and try. It should work by default.
If not set.

```
fallbackNS= false;
```

If STill doesn't Work. Create a new Json variable to pass it to resources.

```
import enLocale from './locales/en.json'
const enLocaleData = {"en":{"transalation":enLocale["en"] }};

 i18next.init({
      debug: true,
      lng: 'en',
      resources: {
        en: enLocaleData 
      });
```

This way, you will be able to pass json with two levels.

```
{
"en":
   {
    "key":"keyValue",
    "key2":"keyValue2",
   }
}
```

Hope it Helps.. :)